# Django slugify text input

Tags: django

How do I take the value entered in a textbox and slugify it before sending it though the form? This doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" value="{{something|slugify}}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript, or add a `clean_FOO` method to your form to sanitise (slugify in your case) your input data.

Comment: Cool, I used JavaScript. Thanks!